# How to click the specific image in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First it will not show the URL in source code, type it below just want to easily to understand.

There are 2 image with the same src and class but they href to different website. Like below

```
<a href='https://www.google.com'><img class="img" src="test.png" ></a>
<a href='https://stackoverflow.com'><img class="img" src="test.png" ></a>
```

If I want to use script to click the first image, what should I do?

I have try 
`$('img[src="test.png"]').trigger('click');`
but it only will click the last one not the first one.

Thank You.

Comment: What are you expecting clicking the image to do? If you're trying to navigate to the URL of the parent `a` element, use `$('img[src="test.png"]').closest('a')[0].click()`. Better still, don't fake DOM events and use `window.location.assign()`

Comment: Or `$('img[src="test.png"]').first().trigger('click');`

Comment: Thx for help :)
Also I find that it can use  $('img[src="test.png"]:eq(0)').trigger('click'); to select the second or the third

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla:

```
function getHref(elHref){
console.log(elHref) // to print it to console..
};

<a onclick="getHref(this.href)" 
href='https://www.google.com'><img class="img" 
src="test.png" ></a>
<a onclick="getHref(this.href)" 
href='https://stackoverflow.com'><img class="img" 
src="test.png" ></a>
```